# what is the best way to register service in Consul

Tags: consul

for example,if i have a Server machine is running ten web applications i called it A , three machines is running Consul and they are in Server Role,where should i register these ten apps?is it the best way to run a Consul Client in A and register these apps in it? or into those Server Consul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all your servers with applications you should install consul agent in client mod.

All applications have different port, right? So, for example, you can register this apps with ID depended on port, like "my_web_application_8080" for apps on 8080 port, "my_web_application_8081" for app on 8081, etc. It's necessary cause service should have uniq id (but can have same name).

All this register request you should send to local agent on `localhost`. Cause this agent connected to servers, all other consul agents will be notified about new service.

Answer (score 0):

I run one instance of [Registrator](https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator) on each node of a Docker environment (not container). Registrator automatically registers Docker containers **with exposed ports** to Consul.

```
docker run -d \
--name=registrator \
--net=host \
--volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
gliderlabs/registrator:latest \
  consul://localhost:8500
```

Comment: it will add port number in the service name.